# Using concat in a class with a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a helper with the following sort of structure;

```
module SomeHelper

 def some_task(&block)
   SomeMethods.new(self, block).some_task
 end

 class SomeMethods< Struct.new(:view, :callback)
  delegate :content_tag, to: :view
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def some_task
     content_tag :div do
       concat content :div, class: 'a' do
         Header
       end
       concat view.capture(&callback)
     end
  end
 end
end
```

The final output should be a div that contains both div.a and the html contained within the helper block in the view. I am getting the following error;

```
undefined local variable or method `output_buffer' for #<SomeHelper::SomeSomeMethods...
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
 def some_task
   capture do
     content_tag :div do  # probably a typo unless you implemented a `content` method
       concat content_tag :div, class: 'a' do
         Header
       end
       concat view.capture(&callback)
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: I tried that, and get ```undefined method `output_buffer=' for #<SomeHelper::SomeMethods:0x007f82bf509a80>```. I have edited the typo you pointed out.

Comment: You are trying to `delegate :content_tag, to: :view`. Unless you have a very good reason to do that and provide for the effect it does, this will mess things up. The call to Rails' `content_tag` method you are using in the helper is being redirected to the `view` instead and I'm not sure what the result of it may be. Try removing that and see if the issue persists. Also, why do you feel you need to explicitly `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to delegate the concat method to view object